# Why is deleted answer (down voted) still visible and reputation still include the down vote?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, deleted-answers

I genuinely deleted an answer to a question that had down vote and explanation why my answer was incorrect [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350416/execution-monitoring-of-ssis-packages/27354837?noredirect=1#comment43176075_27354837). Being a newbie to the field I accept the mistake that I made considering the comment that was given. So to avoid further embarrassment, I deleted it because I still haven't been able to figure out how to fix it. However it is still visible with the downvote. From my reading, users with more than 10k rep can see it but not others. How does that respect the writer who wishes for the answer to be deleted?

Comment: Original author can always see their own deleted content. To see other users' deleted posts, it requires 10k.

Comment: There is nothing embarrassing in being wrong and correcting yourself. It's not correcting yourself or refusing to acknowledge your mistakes that's embarrassing. Don't worry about it.

Comment: In addition to the positive comments others have left about occasionally being wrong, don't think of it as something that only happens to "newbies" or that you should be unwilling to admit mistakes when you aren't one any more. I would take newbie mistakes over an "expert" that is unwilling to admit a mistake any day.

Comment: @senderle If I saw such an edit I would be tempted to roll it back. The right thing to do is to delete the answer, or edit an errata in, not to leave the answer around but remove all its contents.

Comment: @amalloy -- Sorry, could you explain what you mean by "leave the answer around"? The answers I'm thinking of are deleted answers...

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you'd said people were editing answers and *then* deleting them...that just seems weird. I guess there's nothing wrong with it, but what is the point?

Comment: I have seen people edit out the content of a deleted answer and replace it with something like "Never mind.... facepalm" Sometimes it's a very high-rep person! The original answer is still visible in the history, but I've never bothered to look. I'm not sure whether this is encouraged behavior, but it seems pretty harmless to me.

Comment: it really is deleted, you can always see your own deleted answers regardless of reputation score.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> How does that respect the writer who wishes for the answer to be deleted?

It doesn't. Once you have submitted content to the public internet, there's virtually no way to "take it back" and make it unhappen. Regardless of whether Stack Overflow would "respect your wish", your posting has likely already been cached in a dozen caches, crawled by Google and resides in any number of other databases around the web.

If you may be *embarrassed* by content, don't post it. Think twice before posting it, because there's no way to make it disappear from the internet entirely.

And really, we've all been wrong before and will be wrong again. Don't take it too hard. There's no shame in retracting a statement; it's part of the learning process. On the contrary, *not* retracting a wrong answer would be shameful. Just do better next time. :)

Comment: ++. I think only a few do not have bad posts and/or act available on the internet.

Comment: +1 for *"we've all been wrong before and will be wrong again"*. I feel bad for people who've put really idiotic and embarrassing content up online as kids that ends up permanently associated with their name (heck, I have some things I posted on forums when I was 14 that I'd dearly like not to be tied to my name now), but adults need to realise anything you say in public nowadays may be attached to you forever. As long as it's just merely wrong, though, and not, say, a hateful rant or something, it probably won't do you real harm - anyone who says enough interesting things says some wrong ones.

Comment: @Mark I forgot who said this, but: *"Nobody will remember you for your failures. People will remember you for your successes."*

Comment: Obviously though I did not remember the author of the successful above quote, so take that with a grain of salt... ;o)

Answer (score 8):

Posts are never permanently deleted on the site, and that's just that.

The following is taken from the StackExchange FAQ [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/168244):

> ### What does deletion mean for a post?
>
> Deleted posts are usually **not** physically deleted (that is, removed from the system); they're just hidden (AKA soft-deleted). This means they won't appear in search results or data dumps, and normal users following links to them will see [a 404 (not found) page](https://stackoverflow.com/404).
>
> Moderators, and normal users with >=10k reputation, see all deleted posts. Moderators are able to undelete any deleted post. "10kers" may vote to undelete deleted *questions* (it takes three votes to undelete), but cannot undelete deleted *answers*.

The reputation loss as a result of the downvote(s) will be restored, but the post will remain visible to more trusted users.

Comment: Well, aside from [boat programming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131733/224428), anyway.

Answer (score 3):

From [the legal page](https://stackexchange.com/legal) ...

> ... You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and
> license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify,
> create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content ...

In other words, once you've submitted a question or an answer, you lose the right to truly delete it.  Count yourself lucky that Stack Exchange allows you to "soft delete" it some of the time.