# Why are deleted answers containing hate/obscenity still accessible/viewable?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, architecture

I feel that this question can't be answered by anyone other than a core member of Stack Overflow who has worked in or has taken part in the architecture's creation and is being misinterpreted/misunderstood.

---

I happen to find a question (on Stack Overflow) that was listed under "Related", being:

- [How to calculate percentile rank for point totals over different time spans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007146/how-to-calculate-percentile-rank-for-point-totals-over-different-time-spans)

In the answers section, there contains quite a few (deleted) answers given by (obviously) the same person which contained hateful/obscene messages.

**Note:** These can now only be seen by 10k+ members. For those who cannot see them, they contain the "F" word and a few others (not so hate-related, but spam nonetheless).

**Sidenote:** I can provide a screenshot on request by lower than 10k members, but I don't see it as really being necessary.

Why is it that those answers are still viewable/accessible and why can they not be deleted altogether?

I have to note that yes, I did find a related Q&A:

- [Why is deleted answer (down voted) still visible and reputation still include the down vote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278772/why-is-deleted-answer-down-voted-still-visible-and-reputation-still-include-th)

but more specifically [this answer in that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278773/1415724)

And I can understand that. But why is it that posts which clearly contain "hate, obscenity, etc." can still be viewed by some who have that privilege and not (really) deleted from the Stack Overflow database?

I seem to remember a time where deleted answers were in fact "deleted" from the Stack Overflow database and this being a 10k+ rep at the time.

IMHO, they take up space for nothing and they have no use to be seen whatsoever. Plus, it could encourage a younger generation to do so, as well as exposing them to such language/behaviour.

I realize that it would take a lot work for them to be really deleted yes, but I guess **what my real question should have been;** why is it that answers (or even questions) with such language not erased altogether from the beginning?

Anyway, that's just my two cents, and I stand by my values on this.

Comment: care to share your thoughts on the dv there? I feel this is a worthy question. Unless you support that kind of behaviour. So, speak your mind, that's what it's here for.

Comment: if you're going to downvote without saying a word, then I feel it's disrespect towards the question and myself. Please don't insult me. I won't delete the question if that's what you're hoping.

Comment: I'm not a 10ker so I wouldn't know, but I always thought they were replaced by something like "This answer was deleted as offensive; see the revision history to view its content", specifically so privileged users wouldn't have to see the hate.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom *"specifically so privileged users wouldn't have to see the hate"* - and what about members who are like 12-13 years old with 10k+, you feel that it's ok for them to see language like that. I just find that there's already enough bad stuff happening in this world that we're exposed to, that letting Stack still let people be able to see that type of behaviour is shameful. Why on earth didn't they just delete it once and for all, or do they want to show us just stupid/bad people can be? It's total nonsense.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom *"This answer was deleted as offensive"* - Only some, not all. Some I can still see as containing *"f-you bearded f-k welfare santa claus, f-you inbread, etc"* (they mispelled it too) *lol* - And even still; the ones that were changed with a revision history, shouldn't even be there.

Comment: Re: `feel that this question can't be answered by anyone other than a core member of Stack who has worked in or has taken part in the architecture's creation` -> I find that a strange requirement for your question. Arguments to keep these answers as "soft-deleted" or to permanently delete them can be formulated by anyone, not just by the person who implemented it.

Comment: These days, those kinds of content are hidden behind a "this was flagged as spam/offensive" link. There seem to be a couple remnants from before that was introduced; is that *really* a problem? A hard delete would be inadvisable for many reasons, not the least of which is still having the data around in case there's legal issues around something someone has said.

Comment: I've edited the offending content out. The user name is still problematic though and I can't do anything about that.

Comment: If they weren't, where would I get my luls?

Comment: *"and what about members who are like 12-13 years old with 10k+"* 12 year old who were clever enough to earn 10k reputation, but are unable to read the f-word? Huh?

Comment: 12 year old already violating rules of SO knowingly - so should have no problem with reading f-words and other content violating "be nice" guidance. Also I suspect just reading average SO post is more traumatizing experience for someone who used to read old books. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When exactly do you "permanently delete" an answer and when do you "soft delete" an answer?

For those who can't see it, there are five deleted answers on that question with texts such as "fuck you inbread *[sic]*". You're right that this adds nothing of value to the site and could never conceivably do, but what about an answer in the form of:

> The problem is that Windows is fucking stupid and that the developers are inbread morons
>
> [some technical stuff which attempts to answer the question]

Such an answer would most likely gain a number of rude and offensive flags – and rightfully so – but do we *really* want to permanently delete it? It *does* contain actual valid information someone spent time writing.

Completely destroying that is probably not a good thing. Back when I was a mod/admin on various forums I typically sent a personal message with the post's contents when I deleted something, so that no user could complain that posts they spent time writing would be completely lost. One man's incoherent rant is another man's manifesto for the future. *Shrug*.

Where do we put the limit? What is considered "useful enough" to keep?

Just soft-deleting everything avoids this entire discussion, and always does the "safe" thing.

---

A second reason to keep this is that it keeps an trail of a user's misconduct, as well as a full history of activity on a question. This can be important to establish patterns of abuse behaviour. It *could* be programmed in a way that makes it only visible to mods, but why? Does it *really* distract that much for regular 10k+ users? And again, hiding *all* deleted answers for 10k+ users is probably not a good thing, so how do you decide what to hide and what to show?

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in the comments rude/spam posts are usually soft deleted with a message that looks like this:

[image]

"This answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details"

I suspect that this didn't happen in this specific case because the offensive posts were created in 2009. That was in the Before time, in the long long ago...

The only thing to do from here is to drop a moderator flag and let them clean up.

---

Things get "soft deleted", so that moderators and users with moderation privileges can spot patterns of behavior, much like you did:

> In the answers section, there contains quite a few (deleted) answers
> **given by (obviously) the same person** which contained hate/profanity
> messages.

Now, how did you put it together that the messages were from the same person? That's pretty much why it works that way.

Comment: It didn't answer my question, to which I edited; see the edit.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think I covered questions 1 and 2, I'm honestly not entirely sure about question 3, but I suspect that things have always been soft deleted, or have been since 2009.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The soft delete can also serve as a deterrent against users posting rude content and trying to cover their tracks by deleting. When people know that their rudeness is visible no matter what they do, they may refrain from posting it to begin with... Think of it like a "smile you're on camera" sign.

Comment: Why flag for a moderator? The post is still editable, so you can edit out the offensive text.

Answer (score 5):

> ...But why is it that posts which clearly contain "hate-related, profanity, etc." can still be viewed by some who have that privilege and not (really) deleted from the Stack database?
>
> ...IMHO, they take up space for nothing and they have no use to be seen whatsoever. Plus, it could encourage a younger generation to do so, as well as exposing them to such language/behaviour.

I would expect anyone with <s>10K+ reputation</s> this privilege which may be less than 10K on not-yet-graduated sites to be **mature** and capable of dealing with most levels of what they'd see with deleted posts.  Yes, these specific posts are the worst of the worst; **this is why they're removed.**

Honestly, I strongly doubt any 10K+ user would up and decide to parrot profanities after seeing a handful of deleted posts, and if there *are* any, then I ***doubt*** that they're going to stay at that privilege for long.

Also, soft deletion really is the norm.  Only in the circumstance of actual mission critical or highly proprietary information have I actively heard of posts being *hard* deleted.  Everything else builds a case against that user and likely their IP to ban them.

I don't see much to get in a huff about.  Rest somewhat assured that these answers are never indexed and are only accessible to a little over 10,000 users.

Comment: And the boat question is another case http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131733/why-was-the-original-boat-programming-question-deleted